# How to get the type of a key's value from an interface?

Tags: typescript

I have TS interface like:

```
MyInterface {
  'key1': number | string;
  'key2': string;
  'key3': SomeOtherInterface;
}
```

I want to create a new type that uses the properties of MyInterface:

```
MyType<K = keyof MyInterface> = {
  'key': K;
  'value': MyInterface[K];
  'somethingElse': string
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that if the key of MyType is 'key1', the value must be of type `number | string`, and if the key is 'key2' the value must be of type `string` and so on. But my attempt above leads to an error: *Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'MyInterface'*. How should I define MyType?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `MyInterface` keys to `MyType` interface, You need to `extend` MyType:

```
interface MyInterface {
  'key1': number | string;
  'key2': string;
  'key3': SomeOtherInterface;
}
interface MyType extends MyInterface {
  'key': K;
  'value': MyInterface[K];
  'somethingElse': string
}

const myVariabel: MyType;
```

Now `myVariabel` has keys of `MyInterface` and new keys. If you want to make key of `MyInterface` optional, you must extend your type with `Partial<MyInterface>`

Answer (score -1):

```
var indexedArray: { [key: string]: number } = {
    foo: 2118,
    bar: 2118
}

indexedArray['foo'] = 2118;
indexedArray.foo = 2118;

let foo = indexedArray['myKey'];
let bar = indexedArray.myKey;
```